# Winsock TCP connection, send fine but recv firewall blocked

Tags: sockets, tcp, winsock2

I have an application that sends a GET request using winsock on port 80 using a TCP socket. A few users have reported an issue where no response is received, looking at network logs and seeing the network device is getting the data just the app isn't it was clear that the firewall was blocking it.

Having disabled the firewall it then worked fine but what I don't understand is why it was getting blocked. The connection is created from the users computer, it connects fine and sends (which I assumes automatically opens a port) so how can data be lost on the same connection when received? Should I be providing additional winsock settings? Or is there simply no way around stopping the firewall blocking an already active connection?

Here is a stripped down version of the winsock code

```
SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    return -1;


struct sockaddr_in client;
memset(&client, 0, sizeof(client));
client.sin_family = AF_INET;
client.sin_port = htons(80);
client.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(inet_ntoa(*addr_list[0]));

if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client, sizeof(client)) < 0){
    closesocket(sock);
    return -1;
}

if (send(sock, buffer, buflength, 0) != buflength){
    closesocket(sock);
    return -1;
}

//get response
response = "";
int resp_leng = BUFFERSIZE;
while (resp_leng == BUFFERSIZE)
{
    resp_leng = recv(sock, (char*)&buffer, BUFFERSIZE, 0);
    if (resp_leng > 0)
        response += std::string(buffer).substr(0, resp_leng);
    else
        return -1;
}

closesocket(sock);
```

Comment: Clearly your diagnosis is mistaken. The connection couldn't be established if traffic was blocked in one direction. Your response-reading code makes no sense BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` loop exits if a `recv()` returns less than `BUFFERSIZE`. This is wrong -- you must always assume that `recv()` can return any amount of data from 1 byte up to and including the supplied buffer size.

Comment: It also fails to distinguish between end of stream and an error, and if this is HTTP it doesn't begin to implement the response-length provisions of RFC 2616.

Comment: Yes, that too, good point. It also leaks the socket handle if `recv()` fails.